# Função inputmask() para cpf e cnpj

Tags: jquery

Estou usando o plugin [Inputmask](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Easy-jQuery-Input-Mask-Plugin-inputmask.html), o seguinte código JS

```
$("input[id*='cpfcnpj']").inputmask({
    mask: ['999.999.999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99'],
    keepStatic: true
});
```

Meu `input` está pegando a máscara de **cpf**, mas fica travada nela. Quando chega nos 11 dígitos, não habilita a máscara de **cnpj**.

Comment: Olá Matheus, poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar qual plugin você está utilizando?

Comment: Olá Mathes, tudo bem?
Você não precisa alterar o título pare RESOLVIDO, basta aceitar a resposta que lhe ajudou clicando no **sinal de certo** abaixo da pontuação. Não se esqueça que você também pode votar (setinha para cima) nas respostas que lhe foram úteis. 
Lembrando que você sempre pode visitar o [tour] para entender melhor os site.

Comment: Obrigado Randrade, n estou muito acotumado a usar, ainda to aprendendo, mas muito obrigado pela informação

Answer (score 8):

Não entendi muito bem o seu problema. Utilizando [esta biblioteca de InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask), o seu código funciona perfeitamente.

Veja um exemplo dele abaixo.

```js
$("input[id*='cpfcnpj']").inputmask({
  mask: ['999.999.999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99'],
  keepStatic: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>


<input id="cpfcnpj" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ" />
```

Comment: Não sei o que ta acontecendo então

Comment: Funcionou, era a versão do InputMask que eu tava usando, eu vi que no seu exemplo ai ta usando a 3, eu tava usando a 2, valeu

Answer (score 3):

Bom, não precisa de um plugin pra isso:

```js
function mascaraMutuario(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout('execmascara()',1)
}

function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function cpfCnpj(v){

    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"")

    if (v.length <= 14) { //CPF

        //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
        v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")

        //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
        //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
        v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")

        //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
        v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1-$2")

    } else { //CNPJ

        //Coloca ponto entre o segundo e o terceiro dígitos
        v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1.$2")

        //Coloca ponto entre o quinto e o sexto dígitos
        v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2.$3")

        //Coloca uma barra entre o oitavo e o nono dígitos
        v=v.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/,".$1/$2")

        //Coloca um hífen depois do bloco de quatro dígitos
        v=v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/,"$1-$2")

    }

    return v
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="user_cpf" name="user_cpf" placeholder="" maxlength="18" onkeypress='mascaraMutuario(this,cpfCnpj)' onblur='clearTimeout()' required data-error="Informe seu CPF">
```